# NHibernate 3 string-based fetch paths?

Tags: nhibernate, eager-loading

I'm trying to implement a DAO interface with an NHibernate implementation. The interface calls for a Fetch-like method to be exposed, with the following signature:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> AllIncluding(params string[] properties);
```

The EntityFramework equivalent implementation is easy, as they have an Include(string prop) extension method, but I dont' see anything like that in either QueryOver or NHIbernate LINQ; just the Fetch method that takes a Func.  Any ideas how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try something like ?

```
session.QueryOver<Product>()
    .UnderlyingCriteria.SetFetchMode("PropertyName", FetchMode.Eager);
```

As I understand, QueryOver is just a wrapper around Criteria, and Criteria has also a non-typed/string-based version of setting fetch mode.

**Update**

So, your method can look like:

```
public IQueryOver<TEntity, TEntity> AllIncluding(params string[] properties)
{
    var queryOver = session.QueryOver<TEntity>();
    var criteria = queryOver.UnderlyingCriteria;

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        criteria.SetFetchMode(property, FetchMode.Eager);
    }

    return queryOver;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that approach.  One follow-up question, though; if you note, my interface requires an IQueryable<T>, not an IQueryOver<T1,T2>.  Is there a way to use your technique without having to materialize all the data using ToList<T>()?  Ideally, the semantics of IQueryable suggest that i'm returning something chainable w/ deferred execution, i'd like to maintain that if possible.

Comment: Actually, think I found it:  return queryOver.Future<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

Comment: Take care, I don't think IQueryable() is handled by NH (it's linq ext. method to any enumerable). So, I think when you do operations like "Where" or so on the queryable it might be done in memory not in query (and the query brings entire list). Test it to verify if this behavior happens.

Comment: worked, sorry for not upvoting you earlier.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Paul, did the queryOver.Future work or did you end up using IQueryOver?

Comment: @ryanrdl queryOver is of type IQueryOver

Answer (score 1):

Just for convenience ill post and extension version of the method Meligy provided in his solution

```
public static class QueryOverExtensions
{        
    public static IQueryOver<T, T> AllIncluding<T>(this IQueryOver<T, T> source, params string[] properties)
    {
        var criteria = source.UnderlyingCriteria;
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            criteria.SetFetchMode(property, FetchMode.Eager);
        }
        return source;
    }
}
```

now you can call the method like this:

```
queryOver.AllIncluding<TEntity>("property").where(...);
```